# Intellij Putty session embedded in terminal

Tags: intellij-idea

Under settings -> Terminal I have shell path set as C:\Downloads\putty.exe

When I launch a terminal I want to have **putty session embedded in the IDE temrinal** which can access an SSH connection. Instead now putty session pops up in a new window.

Is there something which I have missed.

Answer (score 0):

You want to launch an SSH Terminal instead of a Terminal. You can do this if you have the **Python** plugin installed.

Tools > Start SSH Session and enter your credentials to get started:

[image: Credentials]

You'll end up with a new tab in the Terminal window:

[image: SSH Terminal]

Comment: I dont see "Start SSH Session" option under Tools. Do I have to install any plugin. I am currently on IntelliJ 15.0

Comment: Hmmm, it seems it part of the Python plugin: https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/running-ssh-terminal.html. Sorry about that. I'll update my answer to include that caveat.